From a Generator to a Pandas DataFrame - how do you do this?
Hi lovely community of clever people!
I am trying to load some data from a Redshift table into a pandas DataFrame. I must admit I haven't used Pandas much in my uni days and was more of a numpy kind of guy.
I have managed to use awswrangler to query the data into chunks:
import awswrangler as wr

iterator = wr.redshift.read_sql_query(
    sql="my_query_here",
    con=conn
    chunksize=1000
)


And I could get an iterator object like this:
<generator object _iterate_results at 0x00000152583B78A0>

How do I use this generator to make a DataFrame? The query in itself should also include the columns from the table.
This is probably really quite basic but I was wondering if this is something you knew how to do? Have also tried pulling csv files from an S3 bucket but that seems really quite complicated with the permissions and I am not very good with anything to do with permissions.
I have also tried this HOW - to convert a python generator to pandas dataframe but unfortunately get this error:
b'\x00'


One option may be to read directly from Redshift using SQL Alchemy - although I haven't used RedShift, I have used this method to read / write data from / to MS SQL to / from pandas. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-the-amazon-redshift-sqlalchemy-dialect-to-interact-with-amazon-redshift/

If you use the chunksize parameter, the function will return an iterator of data frames. You can go through them easily:
for df in iterator:
    print(df.head())

The returned df contains your columns and up to chunksize rows.
Note that if you want to have one data frame containing all data in the end, you should drop the chunksize parameter. Merging the data frames would increase the memory consumption significantly if you are not careful.
